# Tensorflow: What are the "output_node_names" for freeze_graph.py in the model_with_buckets model?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I trained a `tf.nn.seq2seq.model_with_buckets` with `seq2seq = tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq` very similar to the example in the [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html).

Now I would like to freeze the graph using `freeze_graph.py`. How can I find the "output_node_names" in my model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose names for the nodes in your model by passing the optional `name="myname"` argument to pretty much any Tensorflow operator that builds a node. Tensorflow will pick names for graph nodes automatically if you don't specify them, but if you want to identify those nodes to a tool like freeze_graph.py, then it's best to choose the names yourself. Those names are what you pass to output_node_names.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the basic concept now, but I am still struggling with the model_with_buckets... I have 4 buckets and each has a RNN, then the embedding_attention_decoder and then the sequence_loss, each consisting of several cells, and I can give them all names. But I cannot see one output node, that I can pass to "output_node_names". Do I need to add like a final node in the code of the seq2seq.py code? And do I have one output node for "output_node_names" or four?

Comment: Which nodes to pass depends on what you want to compute. For example, for an inference graph, you would typically use just the one node that represents the output of the model. Basically --- you should use the node that you would want to pass to session.run() when running your graph. (You don't need to name everything in your graph, just the one or two nodes whose values you want to know.)

Comment: It is still not clear how to freeze this particular seq2seq graph

Comment: can you be more specific where to pass this argument? Is it an argument to the `train.py` script? How do I specify which nodes I want to name?

Answer (score 8):

You can get all of the node names in your model with something like:

```py
node_names = [node.name for node in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

Or with restoring the graph:

```py
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(/path/to/meta/graph)
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, /path/to/checkpoints)
graph = sess.graph
print([node.name for node in graph.as_graph_def().node])
```

You may need to filter these to get only your output nodes, or only the nodes that you want, but this can at least help you get the names for a graph that you have already trained and cannot afford to retrain with `name='some_name'` defined for each node.

Ideally, you want to define a `name` parameter for each operation or tensor that you are going to want to access later.

Comment: Right, in seq2seq model there are thousands of them. And they depend on buckets.

Comment: this yields every node name in the graph, not necessarily output.

Comment: there's a typo there (`resore` should be `restore`). I tried to edit, but edits need to change at least 6 characters... anyone know why?

Comment: +changed  tf.get_default_graph to tf.get_default_graph() ( strange that edits should be 6 char rule for programs